# Rails, where is new_user_path? Don't see any reference to this path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this rails app:

https://github.com/ryanb/govsgo/blob/master/app/views/authentications/index.html.erb

There is a form that as 'new_user_path'

Where is the definition for this symbol?  Is it a symbol??

Just confused as I downloaded the source, and searched for 'new_user' and couldn't find any reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is located in routes.rb with the name `new_user`. It's not in this file.

EDIT:

routes.rb is here: https://github.com/ryanb/govsgo/blob/master/config/routes.rb.

But this is rails 3 format and I don't see new_user route. Run rake routes and you should see one called `new_user`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't downloaded the codebase but if you run `rake routes` you will probably see a route definition for `new_user`.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [config/routes.rb](https://github.com/ryanb/govsgo/blob/master/config/routes.rb) you will see the line `resources :users`. This creates several paths (like `edit_user_path`, `users_path` etc.), amongst them `new_user_path`.

You can see all generated path by running `$ rake routes`.